# Запись из файла С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. Пытаюсь найти сроку в файле, вот код:

```
int TelephoneDirectory::search(const char* data)
{
    FILE* file;
    int numberString{ 0 };
    if (!(file = fopen(this->path_, "r")))
    {
        std::cout << "file opening Error!";
    }
    else {

       const int sizeData{30};
        char* line = new char[sizeData];
       while (!feof(file))
       {
           fgets(line, sizeData, file);
           if (strcmp(line, data) == 0)
           {
               fclose(file);
               return numberString;
           }
           ++numberString;
       }
   }
   fclose(file);
   return -1;
```

}

Метод возвращает -1, но должен вернуть номер строки. Функция strcmp не возвращает 0. Не пойму почему

Answer (score 2):

Понял. Функция fgets добавляет "\n" в конце строки, а в data его нет, поэтому строки не равны

Answer (score 1):

1. Замените

```
int numberString{ 0 };
```

на

```
int numberString = 0;
```

Как я понимаю, в этой переменной у вас число строк.

2.Тоже самое с const int sizeData

```
const int sizeData{30};
```

на

```
const int sizeData = 30;
```

У вас же не массивы!

Comment: это форма инициализации переменной. Проблема не в этом